# Custom foreach results for dynamic proxy class - magic methods?

Tags: php, serialization, proxy, foreach

I need to serialize a proxy class. The class uses __set and __get to store values in an array. I want the serialization to look like it is just a flat object. In other words, my class looks like:

```
class Proxy
{
    public $data = array();
    public function __get($name)
    { 
        return $data[$name] 
    }
}
```

and I want a foreach loop to return all the keys and values in $data, when I say:

```
foreach($myProxy as $key)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Proxy implements IteratorAggregate
{
    public $data = array();
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $data[$name];
    }
    public function getIterator()
    {
        $o = new ArrayObject($this->data);
        return $o->getIterator();
    }
}

$p = new Proxy();
$p->data = array(2, 4, 6);
foreach ($p as $v)
{
    echo $v;
}
```

Output is: `246`.

See [Object Iteration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php) in the PHP docs for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You want to implement the [SPL iterator interface](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)

Something like this:

```
class Proxy implements Iterator
{
    public $data = array();

    public function __get($name)
    { 
        return $data[$name] 
    }

    function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->data);
        $this->valid = true;
    }

    function current()
    {
        return current($this->data)
    }

    function key()
    {
        return key($this->data)
    }

    function next() {
        next($this->data);
    }

    function valid()
    {
        return key($this->data) !== null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have control over the code that will be doing the iterating. It is a 3rd-party library, and I want my proxy to play nice with it. It uses a foreach. Am I right in assuming that implementing the interface would require the person iterating to use the interface functions, or does it do some magic behind the scenes?

Comment: The iterator interface is magic - it lets you use foreach() over your object